# Manipulating advection coefficient in Fipy: Advection Diffusion Equation

Tags: python, vector, pde, coefficients, fipy

I am trying to solve advection-diffusion equation in python using fipy. I would like to manipulate the convection coefficient so that it point at the center of the domain.

My code is

```
from fipy import *

# Setting mesh and discretising space
nx = 10
dx = 1.
mesh = Grid1D(nx=nx, dx=dx)
x = mesh.cellCenters[0]

# Setting variable of results and adding inicial conditions
phi = CellVariable(name="solution variable", mesh=mesh, value=0.)
phi.setValue(1., where=(4 < x) & (6 > x))

# Plotting inicial conditions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    viewer = Viewer(vars=phi, datamin=-0.1, datamax=1.5)
    viewer.plot()

# Diffusion and convection coefficients
D = 1.
C = (1.,)

# Setting PDE
eqX = TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D) - \
                     ConvectionTerm(coeff=C)

# Solving Transient term
timeStepDuration = 0.1
steps = 15
t = timeStepDuration * steps

for step in range(steps):
eqX.solve(var=phi, dt=timeStepDuration)

# Plotting results
if __name__ == '__main__':
    viewer = Viewer(vars=phi, datamin=0., datamax=1.)
    viewer.plot()
```

As you could see, along the time, the wave moves with direction established by  the vector of convection coefficient. How would be the code to manipulate the convection coefficient for the wave moves only towards the center of my domain?

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convection coefficient controls the direction of the traveling wave. For example, to make the wave always travel towards the center of the domain, change the convection coefficient to be

```
C = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, rank=1)
C[:] = 1.
C.setValue(-1., where=x > 5.)
```

This will advect the wave with either velocity 1 if the wave is in the first half of the domain or with velocity -1 if it is in the second half of the domain. If the initial square wave is off center then it will return to the center.

Comment: Hello, I have put your suggestion in my code, but it did not work. It returns an error indicating convection coefficient must to be a vector.

Comment: Apologies, I left out the `rank=1` argument to make the coefficient a vector.